# SQL - Using Sum command multiplies the salary for the same person

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to increase the salary for those employees who treat at least 2 patients by 10%. My problem is that the salary first multiplies by 2 for every patient they treat and then multiplies by 10% at the end. For exampel if the employee earns 25.000 and treats 3 people the new salary becomes 82.500.

```
select distinct t.empNbr, e.Salary, sum(e.Salary*1.1) as NewSalary from Treats t
inner join Employee e
on e.empNbr=t.empNbr
WHERE t.empNbr IN
(
SELECT empNbr
  FROM Treats
  GROUP BY empNbr
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2)
group by t.empNbr, e.Salary
```

Comment: Provide sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CROSS APPLY should help:

```
SELECT  e.empNbr,
        e.Salary, 
        e.Salary*1.1 as NewSalary
FROM Employee e
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT  empNbr
    FROM Treats
    WHERE e.empNbr = empNbr
    GROUP BY empNbr
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) as t
```

The `t` part gets `empNbr` we need. Then we select `empNbr` and `salary` from `Employee` table and do math :)

One more way:

```
SELECT  TOP 1 WITH TIES 
                        e.empNbr,
                        e.Salary, 
                        e.Salary*1.1 as NewSalary
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Treats t
    ON e.empNbr = t.empNbr
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN COUNT(t.empNbr) OVER (PARTITION BY t.empNbr ORDER BY t.empNbr) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.empNbr ORDER BY t.empNbr)
```

Comment: My pleasure! I add one more solution, please, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the right query. Let me know if this works

```
select empNbr, Salary, sum(Salary*1.1) as NewSalary 
from employee 
where empNbr in (select empNbr 
                 from Treats 
                 group by empNbr 
                 having count(*) >=2) ----- Ordered as a code
```

Comment: i get this error: Column 'empNbr' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

Christopher,
 You can use below query to get the result,

```
SELECT  t.empNbr, 
    e.Salary, 
    (e.Salary * e.count +(e.Salary/10) ) as NewSalary
from Treats t
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT empNbr, COUNT(*) AS count Employee GROUP BY empNbr) e
ON e.empNbr=t.empNbr
AND  e.count >=2
```

> Explination

1. We can calculate result without having clause
2.In the inner join, empNbr and the count of that employee in derived
3.Using this count in the select query, the current salary is multiplied and 10% is added with the salary
Hope this is what you need. Any issues, feel free to ask